# Doctrine how to delete cache

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

My doctrine project works fine in localhost. I copied all files to host using FileZilla. Also i took a dump from my mysql and import the hosting machine's phpmyadmin.

When i had tried to run program, doctrine returned an error :

> “No identifier/primary key specified for Entity”

I searched this error google. I think i have to clear cache file. Reference link :

["No identifier/primary key specified for Entity" - extends FOS User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267178/no-identifier-primary-key-specified-for-entity-extends-fos-user)

But i don't know, where cache file is...

I can not access virtual machine terminal, i can access only my ftp and cpanel. I have vendor folder and my functions.

I have no idea, why it works on my localhost but it does not work on live.

Comment: Delete everything in var/cache or app/cache depending on your setup. And it isn't recommended to use a shared host for symfony project.

Answer (score 1):

okay you should run this command on terminal 
For Symfony 3+

```
 php bin/console cache:clear
```

and for symfony 2

```
 php app/console cache:clear
```